# Openstack-autopilot - Landscape and Openstack Dashboard on private network?

Tags: networking, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I have set up Openstack with the Openstack-Autopilot, I have a split network, a public and a private. Following this guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot

Is it correct behaviour that the Landscape and Openstack Dashboard are assigned to the private network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The public network will be used for Openstack floating IPs.

Comment: And what about the MaaS server? Can I have both the network interfaces configured to the private network?

Comment: If you mean both interfaces from the node plugged into the same private network, then yes, you can.